# git ref refs/heads/dashboard-angular does not exist or you do not have permission

Tags: node.js, netlify

I am getting the below error while I am trying to deploy my Angular application to Netlify from bitbucket.

These are the neatlify logs.

```
11:38:49 PM: Build ready to start
11:38:51 PM: build-image version: 7c49b266ed8abd833dee6036ec0a4b9ee887658a
11:38:51 PM: buildbot version: f58df58ab0bceffdcb8d1e60fec992495a2a6751
11:38:51 PM: Fetching cached dependencies
11:38:51 PM: Starting to download cache of 254.8KB
11:38:51 PM: Finished downloading cache in 129.507361ms
11:38:51 PM: Starting to extract cache
11:38:51 PM: Failed to fetch cache, continuing with build
11:38:51 PM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
11:38:52 PM: git ref refs/heads/dashboard-angular does not exist or you do not have permission
11:38:52 PM: Failing build: Failed to prepare repo
11:38:52 PM: failed during stage 'preparing repo': git ref refs/heads/dashboard-angular does not exist
11:38:52 PM: Finished processing build request in 833.373404ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually happens because there are no permissions for Netlify to pull your source code.  Netlify accesses repositories SOLELY via Deploy Key. 
 Netlify cannot automatically install a deploy key on any git service (GitHub, GitLab or BitBucket) unless the installing/logged in user has administrative access privileges.

After acquiring appropriate permissions and re-linking via Netlify's UI, the deploy key was successfully install and pulls in Netlify's CI worked better.

[Netlify's helpdesk](https://www.netlify.com/support) can advise on workflows for cases where administrative access is not available.